# Give an example of a function uniformly differentiable with unbounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of a function   $$f:U\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ uniformly differentiable  with unbounded derivative $f'$, $U\subset\mathbb{R}$ open set.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems very easy if you allow $U$ to be unbounded...

Comment: Yes especially if you work in one dimension

Comment: On the other hand if you require $U$ bounded then $f$ uniformly differentiable $\implies$ $f'$ uniformly continuous $\implies$ $f'$ extends to continuous function on the (compact!) closure of $U$ $\implies$ $f'$ is bounded.

Comment: What do you mean by *uniformly differentiable*?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240296/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-uniformly-differentiable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f(x) = x^{3/2}$ on $U = [0,\infty).$ Then $f'(x) = (3/2)x^{1/2},$ which is uniformly continuous on $U.$ By the MVT, $f'$ is uniformly differentiable on $[0,\infty).$ Since $f'$ is unbounded, we have an example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's work in one dimension: What is the simplest function which is uniformly differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$? In the definition what if you even take epsilon to be zero?