# Limit of difference quotients along sequence of points

Tags: real-analysis

This question addresses an argument in the convergence proof of an SQP method I found in a text book.

Let $f \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be twice continuously differentiable. Let there be given sequences of directions $s_k \to \hat s$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and of step lengths $\sigma_k \to 0$ in $\mathbb R$. Also, let $x_k \to \hat x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $x_{k+1} = x_k + \sigma_k s_k$.

I wish to prove that

$$\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq:lemma}
\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sigma_k}\big(
f(x_k + \sigma_k s_k) - f(x_k)
\big)
- \nabla f(x_k)^\top s_k = 0.
\end{equation}$$

---

By definition of $\nabla f(x_k)^\top s_k$ and by continuity of $\nabla f,$ we have

$$\begin{align}\tag{2}\label{eq:limits}
\lim_{x_k \to \hat x}
\lim_{s_k \to \hat s}
\lim_{\sigma_k \to 0}
\frac{f(x_k + \sigma_k s_k) - f(x_k)}{\sigma_k}
=
\lim_{x_k \to \hat x}
\lim_{s_k \to \hat s}
\nabla f(x_k)^\top s_k
=
\nabla f(\hat x)^\top \hat s.
\end{align}$$

I have a couple of questions:

1. In order to use \eqref{eq:limits} for \eqref{eq:lemma}, I need to argue why it is valid to compute the limits of $\sigma_k,s_k,x_k$ one after another, even though in \eqref{eq:limits} they are approached in parallel. Can you help?
2. Does \eqref{eq:lemma} hold true for any converging sequence $x_k \to \hat x$?
3. Does \eqref{eq:lemma} hold true for any sequence $x_k$, not necessarily converging?

Comment: I believe for the first question, you are dealing with a uniform differentability condition (a multivariable version of what is found in the top answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240296/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-uniformly-differentiable). I believe you will have a uniform approach of $f(x+\sigma s)$ to $\nabla f^\top s$ for all $x, \sigma, s$ uniformly close to $\hat{x}$, $0$, and $\hat{s}$, respectively. 

If that approach works, I don't see why it wouldn't also give a positive answer for question 2.

Comment: For the third question, the answer is no. The reason is because the argument I mentioned above has uniformity over bounded sets (and we are controlling $x_k$ by being near $x$). If we lose this, we lose the uniformity. For example, $f(t)=t^3$, $x_k=k$, $\sigma_k=1/k$, $s_k=s=1$.  Then $$\frac{f(x_k+\sigma_k s_k)-f(x_k)}{\sigma_k} = 3k^2+3,$$ and $$f'(x_k)=3k^2.$$  Thus the difference is always $3$.

Comment: @bangs Many thanks for your comments. I have to think about the argument of uniform differentiability for a moment. I actually thought about the same counterexample that you provided, but failed to properly compute the value of the difference quotient, *LOL*.

Answer (score 0):

By a mean value theorem, there is a number $\alpha_k \in\;]0,1[$ such that
$$
f(x_k + \sigma_k s_k) - f(x_k) = \sigma_k \nabla f(x_k + \alpha_k\sigma_k s_k)^\top s_k.
$$
Subtracting $\sigma_k \nabla f(x_k)^\top s_k$ on both sides leads to
$$
f(x_k + \sigma_k s_k) - f(x_k) - \sigma_k \nabla f(x_k)^\top s_k = \sigma_k\big(\nabla f(x_k + \alpha_k\sigma_k s_k) - \nabla f(x_k)\big)^\top s_k,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\frac{1}{\sigma_k}\big(f(x_k + \sigma_k s_k) - f(x_k)\big) - \nabla f(x_k)^\top s_k
=
\big(\nabla f(x_k + \alpha_k\sigma_k s_k) - f(x_k)\big)^\top s_k.
$$
Using the mean value theorem again, there is some $\beta_k \in \;]0,1[$ such that
$$
\big(\nabla f(x_k + \alpha_k\sigma_k s_k) - f(x_k)\big)^\top s_k
=
\alpha_k\sigma_k s_k^\top \nabla^2 f(x_k + \alpha_k\beta_k\sigma_k s_k)s_k,
$$
and hence,
$$\begin{align}
\left\lVert\big(\nabla f(x_k + \alpha_k\sigma_k s_k) - f(x_k)\big)^\top s_k\right\rVert
&\leq
\alpha_k\sigma_k \left\lVert\nabla^2 f(x_k + \alpha_k\beta_k\sigma_k s_k)\right\rVert \cdot\lVert s_k\rVert^2
\\
&\leq\sigma_k\left\lVert\nabla^2 f(x_k + \alpha_k\beta_k\sigma_k s_k)\right\rVert \cdot\lVert s_k\rVert^2 \to 0,
\end{align}$$
since the spectrum of the Hessian matrix stays bounded.